# Matlab modulo specific behaviour

Tags: matlab

I have the following problem. Let's say I have four possible values `{1 2 3 4}` and  I want a specific behavior of mod function

The behavior I seek is this one

```
 1 mod 4 = 1
 2 mod 4 = 2
 3 mod 4 = 3
 4 mod 4 = 4
```

but I have the following results with matlab.

```
 1 mod 4 = 1
 2 mod 4 = 2
 3 mod 4 = 3
 4 mod 4 = 0
```

Are there any ideas as how to achieve the desired behavior with the simplest way possible in MATLAB?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yeah I can achive the desired behavior if I add an if statement.
ex. res=x mod 4;
if res=0
 res=4;
end

But I want to know if there is a more elegant way to do so!

Comment: What is the desired result for 5, 6, 7, 8,... ?

Comment: @Matt in my problem it doesn't matter, my variable can take values only in {1,2,3,4}

Comment: Then the result is simply the input?

Comment: @Matt you are right my mistake. The variable can take values in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.  And I wish
1 mod4=1 , 2 mod4= 2 , 3 mod4 =3, 4 mod4=4 5 mod4=1, 6 mod4=2, 7 mod4=3, 8 mod4=4.

With mod function I have only one problem in 4 mod4

Comment: Then you have two working solutions below...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
function [result] = my_mod(x,y)
m = mod(x,y);
result = m+~m*y;
```

The `~` negates the result from `mod`, i.e. :

- `~0 == 1`
- `~1 == 0`
- `~2 == 0`
- ...

So we only add `y` if the result from `mod` is `0`.

**demo**

```
>> my_mod(1:8, 4)

ans =

 1     2     3     4     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: it works yes, can you explain the line result = m+~m*y? what exactly does this line do?

Comment: @DimitriC I added a description

Answer (score 7):

If `A` holds those values, you can subtract 1, perform `mod` and add back 1.

Sample run -

```
>> A = 1:8
A =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
>> mod(A-1,4)+1
ans =
     1     2     3     4     1     2     3     4
```