# Selecting neighbours on a circle

Tags: performance, matlab

Consider we have `N` points on a circle. To each point an index is assigned `i = (1,2,...,N)`. Now, for a randomly selected point, I want to have a vector including the indices of `5` points, `[two left neighbors, the point itself, two right neighbors]`.

See the figure below.

[image]

Some sxamples are as follows:

```
N = 18;

selectedPointIdx = 4;
sequence = [2 3 4 5 6];

selectedPointIdx = 1
sequence = [17 18 1 2 3]

selectedPointIdx = 17
sequence = [15 16 17 18 1];
```

The conventional way to code this is considering the exceptions as `if-else` statements, as I did:

```
if ii == 1
    lseq = [N-1 N ii ii+1 ii+2];
elseif ii == 2
    lseq = [N ii-1 ii ii+1 ii+2];
elseif ii == N-1
    lseq=[ii-2 ii-1 ii N 1];
elseif ii == N
    lseq=[ii-2 ii-1 ii 1 2];
else
    lseq=[ii-2 ii-1 ii ii+1 ii+2];
end
```

where `ii` is `selectedPointIdx`.

It is not efficient if I consider for instance `7` points instead of `5`. What is a more efficient way?

Comment: Just pointing out that since you've got the points indexed, their location in 2-space is irrelevant.  If you didn't have the indices, you might have to calculate, say, their angle in  rho-theta space.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft yes the figure is just a simple illustration for making the problem more understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this -

```
off = -2:2
out = mod((off + selectedPointIdx) + 17,18) + 1
```

For a window size of `7`, edit `off` to `-3:3`.

It uses the strategy of `subtracting 1` + `modding` + `adding back 1` as also discussed [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31902880/3293881).

Sample run -

```
>> off = -2:2;
for selectedPointIdx = 1:18
    disp(['For selectedPointIdx =',num2str(selectedPointIdx),' :'])
    disp(mod((off + selectedPointIdx) + 17,18) + 1)
end
For selectedPointIdx =1 :
    17    18     1     2     3
For selectedPointIdx =2 :
    18     1     2     3     4
For selectedPointIdx =3 :
     1     2     3     4     5
For selectedPointIdx =4 :
     2     3     4     5     6
For selectedPointIdx =5 :
     3     4     5     6     7
For selectedPointIdx =6 :
     4     5     6     7     8
....
For selectedPointIdx =11 :
     9    10    11    12    13
For selectedPointIdx =12 :
    10    11    12    13    14
For selectedPointIdx =13 :
    11    12    13    14    15
For selectedPointIdx =14 :
    12    13    14    15    16
For selectedPointIdx =15 :
    13    14    15    16    17
For selectedPointIdx =16 :
    14    15    16    17    18
For selectedPointIdx =17 :
    15    16    17    18     1
For selectedPointIdx =18 :
    16    17    18     1     2
```

Comment: Very elegant oneliner!

Comment: Didn't need the sample, it is very nice answer, thanks!

Comment: Could also write: `out = mod(off + selectedPointIdx - 1, 18) + 1`. I find it clearer. The value 18 is hardcoded once.

Comment: @Tarik Ah yes, that's more intuitive! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use modular arithmetic instead: Let p be the point among N points numbered 1 to N. Say you want m neighbors on each side, you can get them as follows:

```
(p - m - 1) mod N + 1
...
(p - 4) mod N + 1
(p - 3) mod N + 1
(p - 2) mod N + 1
p
(p + 1) mod N + 1
(p + 2) mod N + 1
(p + 3) mod N + 1
...
(p + m - 1) mod N + 1
```

Code:

```
N = 18;
p = 2;
m = 3;
for i = p - m : p + m
    nb = mod((i - 1) , N) + 1;
    disp(nb);
end
```

Run code [here](http://ideone.com/kcCwX4)

I would like you to note that you might not necessarily improve performance by avoiding a if statement. A benchmark might be necessary to figure this out. However, this will only be significant if you are treating tens of thousands of numbers.

Comment: Now I recall, clock arithmetic or as you said modular arithmetic, thanks! +1